# GitHub organization Action failed

Tags: github, github-actions, organization

Can you help to solve this error,

Run Platane/snk/svg-only@v3
with:
github_user_name: sankacrew
outputs: dist/snake.svg?palette=github-dark
github_token: ***
 fetching github user contribution
Error: Action failed with "Could not resolve to a User with the login of 'sankacrew'."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TquSc.png)

Error: Action failed with "Could not resolve to a User with the login of 'sankacrew'."

Comment: it might be because of some bug in the Platane/snk action not your implementation, try their [demo website](https://platane.me/snk/) it is throwing error for all users.